# Why do the generators on my CycleGAN give the same output as input on custom dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network, image-translation

So I followed the tutorial code for image to image translation using cyclegan from [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/what-is-cyclegan/). I am training it on a custom dataset on Keras. What reason could there be for the network to not learn a translation? Both generators in the cyclegan give out the same image that is given as input.

Comment: hey, did you solve that issue?